# Correct Usage FMDB / Memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, memory, fmdb

I have not been able to find a solution to my problem in similar questions. I am extracting a whole bunch of data from a sqlite database using the fmdb wrapper. I have a method in my fmdb utility class similar to this:

```
  - (NSMutableArray *) getConnectionsForKey: (NSString *) key
 {

     NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from user" ];



     FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:query];

     NSMutableArray *retArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];

     while ([ results next ]) {

         NSString *fname = [ results stringForColumn:@"firstname" ];
         NSString *lname = [ results stringForColumn:@"lastname" ];


         NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc ]
                                               init
                                             ];

        [ aDictionary  
          setObject:fname 
          forKey:@"firstname" 
        ]; 

       [ aDictionary 
        setObject:lname 
        forKey:@"lastname" 
       ];



       [ retArray addObject:aDictionary ];

       [ aDictionary release ];


}

[ results close ];

return retArray;
}
```

That stores my info in an array of dictionaries. In my view controller I make a call to my method like so:

```
 -(void) setCurrentConnections: (NSString *) key {

   if ( currentConnections != nil ) {
         [ currentConnections removeAllObjects ];
   }

   LocalDatabase *db = [[ LocalDatabase alloc ] init ];

   [ db openDatabase ];

   currentConnections = [ db getConnectionsForKey:key ];

   [ db closeDatabase ];
  [ db release ];


}
```

Now everytime I call this method to update my array with new contacts, I have a consistent leak that keeps building up as I observe with the allocations tool. This happens even when I release currentConnections right after loading from the database and never call this method again so I am suspecting it is something with the database implementation. Has anyone else handled this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currentConnections is leaking in 'setCurrentConnections'. Here is how I would fix it (notice I also change 'getConnectionsForKey' to return an autoreleased object).

```
 - (NSMutableArray *) getConnectionsForKey: (NSString *) key
 {

     NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from user" ];
     FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:query];

     NSMutableArray *retArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ];
     while ([ results next ]) {

         NSString *fname = [ results stringForColumn:@"firstname" ];
         NSString *lname = [ results stringForColumn:@"lastname" ];
         NSMutableDictionary *aDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc ] init];

        [ aDictionary  
          setObject:fname 
          forKey:@"firstname" 
        ]; 

       [ aDictionary 
        setObject:lname 
        forKey:@"lastname" 
       ];

       [ retArray addObject:aDictionary ];
       [ aDictionary release ];


       }

[ results close ];

return [retArray autorelease];
}


 -(void) setCurrentConnections: (NSString *) key {

   [ currentConnections removeAllObjects ];
   [ currentConnections release];

   LocalDatabase *db = [[ LocalDatabase alloc ] init ];

   [ db openDatabase ];

   currentConnections = [ db getConnectionsForKey:key ];
   [currentConnections retain];

   [ db closeDatabase ];
  [ db release ];

}
```

You can probably skip the call to `removeAllObjects` and just call release. The problem in the original code is that you were overwriting the reference to your existing currentConnection without releasing it first, therefore causing the leak.